# I want to use HTML to dynamically change values and call py functions without screen refreshing

Tags: python, html

I have an app.py and a bunch of classes related to cards, players, and etc. The cards come from a csv in my local repo. In theory the game works just through the terminal, but obviously it's unintuitive and I figured a website is a good home for displaying the game. I'm currently using flask and I've looked at many many many posts relating to this and the answers are summed up to:

1. Flask can only do that if I refresh the page.
2. Use django or ajax.
3. Rewrite everything in JS and use react.

Also as a heads up I'm very much a noob, I only started coding recently and have more of an aptitude for python logic and constructing the game itself, but anything web-related I absolutely suck at as it's a bunch of syntax and annoying nuances that I still don't fully understand. However, if that's really my only option then of course I'll try and familiarize myself but as of right now I don't even know where to start. Any advice would be appreciated, especially if I have the whole thing confused and don't even know what I'm talking about. If you need more code or context let me know.

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session

from cardclass import Card
from playerclass import Player
from helpers import *

app = Flask(__name__)

def main():
    #normally the code goes here
    pass

def gameStart(p1, p2):
    determineFirst(p1, p2)
    p1.drawCard(5)
    p2.drawCard(5)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    human = Player("human")
    opponent = Player("opponent")
    gameStart(human, opponent)
    type = human.type
    protect = human.protect
    hp = human.hp
    hand = human.hand
    #only returns static values of classes
    return render_template(
    "test.html", hp = hp, hand = hand, type = type, protect = protect)

main()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why you set "django" tag if you works with flask?

Comment: The only way to dynamically do this without refreshing the webpage is to use a client side language such as JavaScript or ReactJS.  Flask does indeed require a refresh however you can use JavaScript to call an endpoint/API exposed by flask.

Comment: Got it, I figured there's no working around using JS. I was hoping there'd be another way but i have much to learn it seems, thanks for the comment